# Javascript function declaration with same arguments

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, javascript-function-declaration

I am learning javascript myself. I found if I declare a function with same arguments it just working fine:

```
function func(a, b, a){
  return b;
}
alert(func(1,2,3));
```

But if I do this :

```
function func(a, b, a = 5){
  return b;
}
alert(func(1,2,3)); 
//Firebug error - SyntaxError: duplicate argument names not allowed in this context
```

Then its not working anymore. What is the logic behind that it was working for first equation but not for second one ?

Comment: You should try using strict mode for these. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2y0gryrL/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ES2015 (the newest stable spec for the language) allows parameters to be declared with default values. When you do that, the language won't allow you to re-use a parameter name.

When you're not doing any parameter defaults, the language allows the old "sloppy" re-use of parameter names. If you enable "strict" mode interpretation, you'll get an error for your first example too.

Comment: But into strict mode I can declare same variable twice (I just tested). But its not allowing same for function arguments.

Comment: @Marymon yes, that's correct. Redundant `var` declarations are allowed, I suspect because too much old code would break, and because (thanks to the semantics of `var`) they don't really hurt anything. JavaScript has a long, strange history, and there are many things about it that may seem inconsistent.

Comment: It's essentially `undefined` variable being assigned to other `undefined` variable issue internally.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation)

> 8. If parameterNames has any duplicate entries, let hasDuplicates be true. Otherwise, let hasDuplicates be false.
>
> 21.b
>
> NOTE Early errors ensure that duplicate parameter names can only occur
> in non-strict functions that do not have parameter default values or
> rest parameters.

So, your JS engine ensures that if one of the parameter has default values and `hasDuplicates` is true then it throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN, this kind of check is done by JS internally in case of defaults

```
function go() {
  return ":P"
}

function withDefaults(a, b = 5, c = b, d = go(), e = this, 
                      f = arguments, g = this.value) {
  return [a,b,c,d,e,f,g];
}
function withoutDefaults(a, b, c, d, e, f, g){
  switch(arguments.length){
    case 0:
      a
    case 1:
      b = 5
    case 2:
      c = b
    case 3:
      d = go();
    case 4:
      e = this
    case 5:
      f = arguments
    case 6:
      g = this.value;
    default:
  }
  return [a,b,c,d,e,f,g];
}

withDefaults.call({value:"=^_^="});
// [undefined, 5, 5, ":P", {value:"=^_^="}, arguments, "=^_^="]


withoutDefaults.call({value:"=^_^="});
// [undefined, 5, 5, ":P", {value:"=^_^="}, arguments, "=^_^="]
```

Now in your case, this is something like this -

```
case 0:
    a
case 1:
    b
case 2:
    a = a
```

But when executing case 2, `a` is still not defined, and hence it through in error scenario.

See details here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters

Answer (score 0):

> Argument name must be unique; if you use same name for two arguments and then interpreter get confuses which one you want to access;

Same you added in code as comment

```
//Firebug error - SyntaxError: duplicate argument names not allowed in this context
```

> "Default function parameters allow formal parameters to be initialized with default values if no value or undefined is passed." [Default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters) in ES2015